# Git hanging after cancelling large push

Tags: git, github

I made a mistake on my .gitignore file and accidentally started to push up a large directory with a very large amount of files (to Github). Realising what I did I cancelled the push (`ctrl + c`) part way through.

I ran `git reset --soft HEAD^` and `git reset` to revert the commit and unstage my files. I then updated my .gitignore file.

Checking `git status` again I see all the correct files are ready to be pushed up to Github again, so I added, committed and pushed them.

Thing is `git push origin master` now seems to hang - nothing happens. I'm guessing because I cancelled the last push part way through.

Would anyone know how I could fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try first to clone your GitHub repository again, in a new folder.

Report all (or at least some) of your current modifications to your new local clone.
Add, commit and push from there, to see if the issue persists.

Your local index of your current local cloned repository might be in an incoherent state: a new local clone might help.